# Stripe publish key stored in .env can't be read by React

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm building an e-commerce site, the Cart page holds the checkout process's button.

I created an `.env` file inside front-side folder, then pasted in my **Publishable key**:

**.env** code:

```
REACT_APP_STRIPE = pk_test_51LJh5TCx0CP76PWrc0hRSESvbF00x8voeXAS...
```

**Cart.jsx** page code:

```
import StripeCheckout from "react-stripe-checkout";

const KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE;
//...
            <StripeCheckout
              name="ShopTn"
              image="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTWHNj9PK7N9WLGXRF5FDbA7XdtjH6caLiwnBW2__PWC3crRyS_XiocBVKnP9GONqvVp9A"
              description={`Your total is ${cart.total} DT`}
              billingAddress
              shippingAddress
              amount={cart.taotal * 100}
              currency="TTD"
              token={onToken}
              stripeKey={KEY}
            >
              <Button
                style={{
                  border: "none",
                  width: 120,
                  borderRadius: 5,
                  padding: "20px",
                  backgroundColor: "black",
                  color: "white",
                  fontWeight: "600",
                  cursor: "pointer",
                }}
              >
                CHECKOUT NOW
              </Button>
            </StripeCheckout>
```

**Warning errors i'm receiving:**

I'm getting this error in console.dev:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `stripeKey` is marked as required in `ReactStripeCheckout`, but its value is `undefined`.

Edit (Please ignore this edit part):
upon pressing CHECKOUT NOW `button`, i'm expecting to open stripe checkout interface directly, but i'm getting this JS alert saying:

> Stripe Checkout is missing the required `key` parameter. Please contact the website owner or support@stripe.com.

Edit:

I tried put my publishable key in JSX (like this code below) and it works fine:

```
const KEY = "pk_test_51LJh5TCx0CP76PWrc0hRSESuLLs9TSjpI7bUnDdgu4r0w";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error you are receiving is about a `.map` you are using in the Cart method that is not settings key property to each element created [Read this for more information](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

You have a spelling mistake in `amount={cart.taotal * 100}`.

And verify that the .env variables are getting loaded, for example by putting them into the JSX and verify their content.

Edit:

The code is all working correctly, the problem was solved by restarting the project after editing the .env, as it doesen't reload the key if using nodemon or similars (unlike next.js).

Comment: Thank you @scar, i fixed spell mistake, i removed the map related error, so my question can focus on stripe key issue :) . i puted my publish key in JSX and it's loaded correctly.

Comment: Ok im going to try it, and gonna publish a snippet that works.

Comment: @Michael Check my edit.

Comment: I double checked my API KEY that i used, and it's public key. Also, `console.log(KEY);` print `undefined` in console.dev, where i'm expecting to print my public key. which means react doesn't reach `.env` file.

Comment: Is your .env file in the root of the project?

Comment: .env file created inside `front` folder (in the same location where `src` folder located), exactly like `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246494/discussion-between-michael-and-scar).